# Moments for Steinhaus random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $f_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be independent Steinhaus random variables, i.e. variables which are  uniformly distributed on the complex unit circle. Suppose that $\|f\|_{\infty}> b \|f\|_2$, where $b<1$ and $\|f\|_{\infty}$ is the maximum part of the real parts of $f_i$. Let $a \in R^n$.

Find  $E\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf_i a_i\right)^q$, for $-3\leq q <0$

Comment: How are the $f_i$ related? Are they independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent. Thank you for noticing, I missed it.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what the statement $||f||_\infty > b||f||_2$ means. Assuming that $f = (f_1, ..., f_n)$ the quantities involved are random and the statement isn't true in the almost sure sense for any positive $b \neq 0$.

Comment: This statement is a condition on $f=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)$. Take $b=1\sqrt 2$. The condition states that $\|f\|_{\infty}=max{f_i}> 1/\sqrt 2 (\sum_{i}f_i^2)^{1/2}$

Comment: So you're looking for the conditional mgf?

Comment: Yes, it would be conditional MGF

Comment: Is $\|f\|_{\infty}$ the maximum modulus of the $f_i$, which is trivially $1$? Or is it the maximum of the real parts of the $f_i$?

Comment: It is maximum of the real part